# How can I fix this build issue in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, build

I'm using Unity3D, Vuforia, Native Gallery, NatShare and NatCorder. When I try and compile, I'm getting the following error. How would I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just as a heads up for future questions, it's generally not ideal to just post a screenshot of an error. Instead, copy the problem stack trace text into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an apple certificate? Have you log in with your developer account in xcode?
That's the problem.

Comment: Do you have an apple certificate? - yes develop and distribution. Have you log in with your developer account in xcode? - as publisher

Comment: @МаксимСикайло the problem should be in the certificate. That's the error code that you get when xcode fail to sign your app (for any reason).